# Bash string length check- [: : integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to do the follow in a systemd unit file. I am facing 2 problems here

1. publicIPAddress could be empty string and hence I thought ipLength should be zero and this should not cause  [: : integer expression expected error but I am getting the error.
2. ipLength seems to be empty every time, even for valid value of publicIPAddress. Am I missing something ?

```
/bin/bash -c '\
              ENV="/etc/environment"; \
              touch $ENV; \
              if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then  \
                 echo "****** Could not modify $ENV .. Exiting .."; \
                 exit 1; \
              fi; \
              while true; do \
                 publicIPAddress=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4); \
                 ipLength=${#publicIPAddress}; \
                 echo "************************************$ipLength..."; \
                 if [ "$ipLength" -gt 0 ]; then  \
                  echo "************************************ HURAHHHHHH  .."; \
                  break; \
                 fi; \
                 sleep 1; \
              done'
```

Output of /bin/bash -xc

```
Apr 22 19:20:27 coreosextc-cluster-ws-machine-crgdulh4xle4.novalocal bash[3640]: ++ curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
Apr 22 19:20:28 coreosextc-cluster-ws-machine-crgdulh4xle4.novalocal bash[3640]: + publicIPAddress=10.1.2.3
Apr 22 19:20:28 coreosextc-cluster-ws-machine-crgdulh4xle4.novalocal bash[3640]: + ipLength=
Apr 22 19:20:28 coreosextc-cluster-ws-machine-crgdulh4xle4.novalocal bash[3640]: + echo '************************************...'
Apr 22 19:20:28 coreosextc-cluster-ws-machine-crgdulh4xle4.novalocal bash[3640]: ************************************...
Apr 22 19:20:28 coreosextc-cluster-ws-machine-crgdulh4xle4.novalocal bash[3640]: + '[' '' -gt 0 ']'
Apr 22 19:20:28 coreosextc-cluster-ws-machine-crgdulh4xle4.novalocal bash[3640]: /bin/bash: line 0: [: : integer expression expected
Apr 22 19:20:28 coreosextc-cluster-ws-machine-crgdulh4xle4.novalocal bash[3640]: + sleep 1
```

Comment: What are you seeing from that `echo` line about what `$ipLength` contains? Or is "ipLength seems to be empty every time" indicating that you see `***...`?

Comment: Add `-x` to the execution of this and what do you get?

Comment: ************************************... is what i get for the " echo "************************************$ipLength..."; \" command

Comment: Are you asking me to do /bin/bash -x rather than /bin/bash -c ?

Comment: `/bin/bash -xc` but yes.

Comment: Updated the question with the requested output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75971/discussion-between-karthikj-and-etan-reisner).

Comment: remove " (double quotes) around ipLenth within your if statement. It'll work --OR if you want to use quotes, then instead of using -eq, use == "0". I would also recommend to use 2 big brackets instead of single i.e. if [[ $ipLength -eq 0 ]]; then echo giga; else echo koba; fi  ...... OR .... if [[ "$ipLength" == "0" ]]; then .... ; else ... ; fi

Comment: @ArunSangal A quoted number is just fine in an `-eq` comparison. The problem is that `$ipLength` is not `0` but rather the empty string. The problem seems to be that the systemd unit file that this script is in is mis-handling the `#` in that expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem here is that this script is being embedded in a systemd unit file.

It seems that systemd itself understands `${var}` expansions and is expanding `${#publicIPAddress}` before the script even sees it.

Escaping the `$` with another `$` will protect it from systemd doing this.

So use

```
ipLength=$${#publicIPAddress};
```

instead of

```
ipLength=${#publicIPAddress};
```

in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **"** (double quotes) around *ipLength* variable within your if statement.

Then it'll work --OR if you want to use quotes, then instead of using **-eq**, use **== "0"**.

I would also recommend to use 2 big brackets instead of single i.e.

```
if [[ $ipLength -eq 0 ]]; then echo giga; else echo koba; fi
```

...... OR ....

```
if [[ "$ipLength" == "0" ]]; then echo Hurra -- ipLength=0 ; else echo ipLength=$ipLength; fi
```

For ex:

```
[c1000@s10 giga]$ a=; if [ "$a" -eq 0 ]; then echo giga; else echo koba; fi
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
koba
[c1000@s10 giga]$ a=''; if [ "$a" -eq 0 ]; then echo giga; else echo koba; fi
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
koba
[c1000@s10 giga]$ a=""; if [ "$a" -eq 0 ]; then echo giga; else echo koba; fi
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
koba
[c1000@s10 giga]$

[c4000@s10 giga]$ a="1"; if [ "$a" -eq 0 ]; then echo giga; else echo koba; fi
koba
[c1000@s10 giga]$ a="1.2.3.4"; if [ "$a" -eq 0 ]; then echo giga; else echo koba; fi
-bash: [: 1.2.3.4: integer expression expected
koba
[c1000@s10 giga]$ a="1.2.3.4"; if [ "$a" -eq "0" ]; then echo giga; else echo koba; fi
-bash: [: 1.2.3.4: integer expression expected
koba
[c1000@s10 giga]$ a="1.2.3.4"; if [ "$a" == "0" ]; then echo giga; else echo koba; fi
koba
[c1000@s10 giga]$
```

Comment: The problem here is not "why is `[` giving that error" but rather "why is $ipLength the empty string".